# Looking for review articles on big bang nucleosynthesis

Tags: big-bang

Can someone point to a good review article covering contemporary developments in big bang nucleosynthesis, beyond what's covered in Kolb and Turner's *The Early Universe*? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since there hasn't been any answer from experts, I did some search myself. This well cited article seems to be very comprehensive: [Primordial Nucleosynthesis: from precision cosmology to fundamental physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0631)
It painstakingly walks through the implications of BBN on all kinds of physics models, including exotic ones like large extra dimensions and brane inflation.